# Using a Swift extension method in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift, extension-methods, cgimage

I have an objective-c project which includes a swift file. I've created the bridging header and imported the ProjectSwift.h into the main file etc.

I am trying to use methods from the extensions stored in the Swift file, but am confused by the syntax. When it was class methods I used @objc in front of my Swift methods, but currently with the extensions I have no @objc or @nonobjc (when I put @objc in front of the extension declaration I got:

> Method cannot be in an @objc extension of a class (without @nonobjc) because Core Foundation types are not classes in Objective-C

And if I tried @objc in front of individual methods I got:

> Method cannot be marked @objc because Core Foundation types are not classes in Objective-C

My Swift code:

```
extension CGImage {
    public func someFunction(var1: Int, var2: Int){
        return someThing(someVariables)
    }
}
```

My Objective-C:

```
#import "MyProject-Swift.h"

CGImage *temp = someFunction(var1, var2);//Must use 'struct' tag to refer to type 'CGImage'

#import "MyProject-Swift.h"

struct CGImage *temp = someFunction(var1, var2); //Implicit declaration of function 'someFunction' is invalid in C99
```

And the method is not showing up with autocomplete so I'm guessing I'm screwing up the syntax in my ObjC code or I need some different extension version of @objc in my Swift code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error tells all. `CGImage` isn't a class in Objective-C. You can't use a Swift extension to `CGImage` in Objective-C. You can only use a Swift extension in Objective-C if the Swift extension is on something that is a class in Objective-C.

In short, there is no way you can use your `someFunction` in your `CGImage` extension in your Objective-C code.

Comment: For reference, compare with how you use CoreGraphics types in ObjC/C. All APIs are C free functions that take instances as a parameter, not ObjC method calls.